# Understanding convergence of $a_n := \frac{2n^3 +n^2 +3}{n^3-4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We proved by definition that the sequence $a_n := \frac{2n^3 +n^2 +3}{n^3-4}$ converges.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N := \lceil \frac{24}{\epsilon} \rceil + 2 $.

Then for all $n \geq N$ it holds, that

$$|a_n - 2| = \big |\frac{2n^3+n^2+3}{n^3-4} - \frac{2n^3-8}{n^3-4} \big | = \big | \frac{n^2+11}{n^3-4} \big | = \frac{n^2+11}{n^3-4} \leq \frac{n^2+11}{n^3 - \frac{1}{2}n^3} \leq \frac{12n^2}{\frac{1}{2} n^3} = \frac{24}{n} < \epsilon $$

What I don't understand is how we get to $$- \frac{2n^3-8}{n^3-4} $$

Could someone explain? Thanks

Comment: That's $-2{}{}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$-\frac{2n^{3}-8}{n^3-4}=-\frac{2(n^3-4)}{n^3-4}=-2.$$

Comment: Why do I always fail to see these things

Comment: It's expressing $-2$ as a fraction with denominator $n^3-4$.

Comment: Yeah I get it now, but when I looked at it the first time I didn't get the eureka moment.
Thank you :)

Comment: @PoliticsStudent: when you see a ratio of polynomials, the first reflex is to compare the degree of the numerator and denominator, and extract the "polynomial part" of the fraction, by long division (in this case, just $2$).

Answer (score 1):

I like to do these by dividing out the highest power of the variable.  You get $\dfrac{2n^3+n^2+3}{n^3-4}=\dfrac{2+1/n+3/n^3}{1-4/n^3}\to2/1=2$.